# Error time out, Upload excel file with excel_reader in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, excel, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I want to upload excel file into database by codeigniter. The project has already run with small size excel file. But, if I upload little big size excel file, It can't run.

The problem is maximum execution time. This is the error message:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\bisabisa\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php on line 221
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 221

Backtrace:
```

When I open mysqli_driver.php line 221, this is the code:

```
protected function _execute($sql)
    {
        return $this->conn_id->query($this->_prep_query($sql));
    }
```

It doesn't have the code which named excecution time or relation word with them.

So, what file I have to change?

I use xampp and phpmyadmin. If I upload the file from phpmyadmin, It can run.

Comment: set_time_limit( 360 );

Comment: what file I have to change with that code?

Comment: any of them will work, preferably where it is first called from, 360 seconds, although you may run out of memory as well.

Comment: but in mysqli_driver.php, there is not code who has set_time_limit.

Comment: which file I must change?

Comment: What? 30 seconds execution time is the default for php.  This just increases that to 360s for the script that has that set in it.  As I said any of the files that are part of the stack used to execute what you are executing, no grantee that will be enough time or that you have enough memory.

Answer (score 0):

Do the below changes to solve your issue:

At line 103 in system/core/CodeIgniter.php

```
if (function_exists("set_time_limit") == TRUE AND @ini_get("safe_mode") == 0)
{
    @set_time_limit(300);
}
```

I try to change the value and it works.